# SQL query to get distinct values from grouped records of each column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose, I have a songs table

```
Table name: Songs
- id
- artist
- composer
- lyricist
```

I want to write a sql query so that I can get distinct values from the records, which are grouped by id.
Example:

```
Id Artist Composer Lyricist
1  a1      c1       l1
1  a2      c1       l1
1  a1      c2       l1
2  a3      c1       l2
2  a4      c1       l3
```

The query should return

```
Id Artist Composer Lyricist
1  a1, a2  c1, c2   l1
2  a3, a4  c1       l2, l3
```

If I can get a generic SQL query, i.e., not specific to certain database functionality, it would be great. Please note that, the columns may differ in different table, so it's better, if I don't have to write each column name in the query.

Please, if anyone can suggest something.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Here, I am working with Postgresql, but would like a generic sql query, working on any relational database.

Answer (score 1):

The Postgres SQL version uses `string_agg()` or `array_agg()`:

```
select id,
       string_agg(distinct artist, ','),
       string_agg(distinct composer, ','),
       string_agg(distinct lyricist, ',')
from t
group by id;
```

The generic SQL version is called `listagg()`.

Comment: Ya, I agree to it. But, I actually don't want specific to column query, I mentioned about it, in the question. What I want is, if suppose, I have different table with more columns, it should automatically update, I shouldn't be writing every column in listagg myself.